# Proof that a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Here is a subset of $ \Bbb R^2 $ :

$ A = [(x_1, x_2) \in\Bbb R^2 : x_1 - x_2^2 = 0] $

I am trying to prove that it is not a vector subspace.

1. It is not empty, the $(0,0)$ vector works
2. It is closed under scalar multiplication (sign of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are changed but it works)
3. I was a bit struggling to prove that it does not work for all $x_1$ and $x_2$ (**Is it possible ?**)

I have chosen to take an $u = (1, -1)$ and $v = (16, 4)$. Both of them are in $\Bbb R^2$.
When I do $u + v$, I got a vector that is $(17, 3)$. This vector is not in $A$ since $x_1 - x_2^2 \neq 0$

**My question : Is there something wrong in my reasoning / solution ?**

Comment: "*It is closed under scalar multiplication*" This also doesn't hold.  $(1,1)$ is an element of your space since $1-1^2=0$ is true, but $2\cdot (1,1)=(2,2)$ is not since $2-2^2\neq 0$.  Recall that the scalar multiplication property is that for *all* scalars $\alpha$ in your scalar field and *all* vectors $v$ in your proposed vector space that $\alpha v$ would also be a vector in your proposed vector space.  It sounds like maybe you only checked the scalar $-1$ or something, it is unclear what you think you did here.

Comment: Your example with $u,v \in S$ but $u+v \not \in S$ is correct; this shows that it's not a vector space. As JMoravitz pointed out, #2 does not hold. Out of curiosity, how did you determine that "sign of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are changed but it works"?

Comment: "*...to prove that it does not work* **for all** $x_1$ *and* $x_2$..."  If you want to prove it *is* a vector space you need to prove that it *does* work for all in your space...  If you want to prove it is *not* a vector space then you only need to find at least one example where it doesn't work.

Comment: I mixed up my counterexemple. I was working on a simple vector v = (9,3). If you take a lambda (scalar) = -1. I see now that it is not closed either under scalar multiplication

Comment: You could also have considered $u+u=2u$ to show it is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't feel anything is wrong with your reasoning.

In general, for any $ a \in \mathbb{R}, (a^2, \pm a) \in A$.

Let $ a \neq 0. \ (a^2,a)+(a^2,-a) = (a^2,0) \not\in A.[\text{Closure Property Fails}] $

Answer (score 0):

Following JMoravitz counterexemple for 2) :
Take v = (1, 1) and multiply it by a scalar = 2, it does not fit in A.

On the 3, my counterexemple works and prove that A is not a vector space